# kendo tree view check boxes issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have kendo tree view with check boxes. When i do the button click the values are getting lost after refresh. I wanted to show back to the user after button click could you please help me on this.

```
$("#treeview1").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    dataSource:EquipmentTypes,
    id: ["EquipmentTypeId"],
    dataTextField:["EquipmentTypeName"],
    expanded: false,
    spriteCssClass: "rootfolder",
    dataValueField: ["EquipmentTypeId"],
    value:"@Model.UtilizationFilter.EquipmentTypeFilter"
});
```

Comment: can someone help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because the button in the question does a post of a form. If that is the case then I don't see any easy solutions.

You could either change the buttons so they fetch via ajax. Or add a change event to the tree and then save the values in hidden fields and set them manually after load.

```
.Events(e => e.Check("onCheck"))
```

Comment: ya i am doing the same but the problem here is first i have selected 3 checkboxes and i am showing that then i add 2 more when i check it is showing only the latest selected one's